# Let $f,g:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(1)<0<f(0)$, $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f+g$ is nondecreasing, Prove that $\exists x_0\in [0,1],f(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I got this problem:

Let $f,g:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ be functions such that $f(1)<0<f(0)$, $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f+g$ is nondecreasing on $[0,1]$.
Prove that there exist $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

My try: 
Let's define a set $A=\{x\in[0,1]| 0\leq f(x)\}$,
Since $0<f(0)$ we get that $0\leq f(0)$ and so $0\in[0,1]$ which implies that $A\neq \emptyset$, Now since $1$ is an upper bound of $A$ we get that $\sup(A)$ exists. Set $x_0=\sup(A)$. Now let's define a function $h :[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ by the rule $\forall x\in[0,1], h(x)=f(x )+g(x)$, Now since $h $ is non decreasing in $[0,1]$ we get that $\forall x\in A, g(x )\leq h(x) \leq h(x_0)$

Now any help on how to continue/alternative solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Next, $g$ is continuous thus $h(x_o)\ge g(x)$ gives $h(x_o)\ge g(x_o)$, and so $f(x_o)\ge0$ then notice that$g(1)>h(1)\ge h(x_o)\ge g(x_o)$ . Since $g$ is continuous $\exists t\ge x_o$ such that $g(t)=h(x_o)$. Then $h(t)\ge h(x_o)=g(t)$, so that $f(t)\ge0$. But since $x_o$ is the supremum of $A$ we must have $t=x_o$, so that $h(x_o)=g(x_o)$ implying $f(x_o)=0$

Comment: By the way, is $x_0$ must be in $A$? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: just to have assurance that it lies in $[0,1]$

Comment: I still do not get why $\forall x\in A, g(x)\leq h(x) \leq h(x_0)$ implies that $g(x_0)\leq h(x_0)$ (since we do not know wether $x_0\in A$) ?

Comment: $g(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ so we're taking $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_o}$ both sides

Comment: Does there exist a left or right neighborhood of $x_0$ such that each $x$ in this neighborhood satisfies $g(x)\leq h(x_0)$ and so we will be able to conclude that $g(x_0)\leq h(x_0)$ by continuity ?

Comment: We must have a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that each $x$ in that neighborhood will satisfy $g(x)\leq h(x_0)$ before we can conclude that $g(x_0)\leq h(x_0)$.

Comment: using the definition of supremum we can say that for each $\displaystyle \epsilon>0 \exists x_{\epsilon}\in A$ such that $\displaystyle x_o-\epsilon < x_{\epsilon}<x_o$ thus in particular  if we choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ then we get a sequence of points $\{x_n\}$ in A converging  to $x_o$ thus using $h(x_0)\ge g(x_n) \forall n\in \Bbb{N}$ we get $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_0)\ge \lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n) \implies h(x_o)\ge g(x_o)$